# Android - will saving in onPause() cover saving in onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android

While being in the beginning phase of my app development, I was using `onSaveInstanceState()` to save my data in `Bundle` and restore my state in `onCreate()` in Activity - this helps quick testing during rotation, for instance. Then I decided that some of my data, lets say just an integer, should be persisted between runs, so I decided to write it in private `SharedPreferences` of the Activity in `onPause()`. **The question is:** can I safely remove the Bundle save/restore version in `onSaveInstanceState()` and rely only on persistent version of saving or should I keep both and in `onCreate()` check both sources, taking whichever is present?

I dug a lot here for similar posts and some people say that they use the following pattern in `onCreate()`:

```
if (savedInstance != null && ...contains the saved data...) {
    ...use the saved data...
} else {
    ...load the saved data from preferences...
}
```

So I wonder if there is a scenario that will went through `onSaveInstanceState()` and not through `onPause()` which will make me also saving the same stuff in `Bundle`? I want to use only the **`else`** part above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no scenario when you will not get into **onPause** method (except you call finish in onCreate), because this method is the main part of an Activity life cicle.

But there is a scenario when **onSaveInstanceState** will not be called in 4.0+ devices. It can happen if there is extremely low memory on device and a new activity with big memory needs is going to be shown on screen.